# Create key/value pair in Python using an if conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3.5, is it possible to build a dictionary key/value pair using an `if` statement?

For example, given the following `if-conditional`:

```
if x == 1:
    color = 'blue'
elif x == 2:
    color = 'red'
else:
    color = 'purple'
```

How can I create a dictionary key/value pair that incorporates this `if-conditional`?

```
dict(
    number = 3,
    foo = 'bar',
    color = 'blue' if x == 1, 'red' if x == 2, else 'purple'
)
```

Comment: Does the key `color` needs to change dynamically or it needs to be defined only at the creation of the dictionary? Explain better what you want to accomplish in general, or why you want to do this, so that maybe we can give you alternatives eventually.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters points out, you really just need to change the syntax from `if x == 1, 'red' if x == 2, else 'purple'` to `if x == 1 else "red" if x == 2 else "purple"`

Comment: @nbro thanks for the comment.  I will be sure to provide more information in future posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key must be a non-mutable (pronounced: "hash-able") object. This means a string, tuple, integer, float, or any object with a `__hash__` method. The dictionary you are creating seems to need this:

```
x = 2
d1 = {
    "number": 3,
    "foo": "bar",
    "color": "blue" if x == 1 else "red" if x == 2 else "purple"
}
# or:
x = 3
d2 = dict(
    number=3,
    foo="bar",
    color="blue" if x == 1 else "red" if x == 2 else "purple"
)
print(d1["color"]) # => red
print(d2["color"]) # => purple
```

As @timgeb mentioed, the more generally preferred way is to use the `dict.get` method since longer if-conditional statements become less and less readable.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the commas in the if-statement which seem to be entirely invalid syntax. Also, I'm aware of the kwargs thing you mentioned, but that's not how I read the question. My brain threw "{" and "}" in there instead of the dict constructor. As you know, `d = {number=3, whatever=True}` is not valid Python, which is how I'd originally read it.

Comment: Right, then your statement is confusing. Yes, the commas are invalid syntax, but I doubt the OP ever realised that what comes after a comma must be another key-value pair.

Comment: Understood. Removed the unnecessary commentary.

Comment: What remains then is confusion as to why you mention the requirement at all. :-) And technically, the requirement is that the object is *hashable*. It is fine to have a mutable object as a key, provided that whatever informs the hash remains stable. So a custom class with a `__hash__` method based on attributes `foo` and `bar` is free to have an attribute `spam` that is mutated.

Comment: That is certainly true, but I'm not entirely sure that it's relevant for such a small issue on if conditionals.

Comment: @Goodies - yes, I am a Python noob (and programming in general).  Noobs like me appreciate your replies/answers :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not to use the conditional, but a mapping of numbers to colors instead.

```
>>> x = 2
>>> dict(
...     number = 3,
...     foo = 'bar',
...     color = {1: 'blue', 2: 'red'}.get(x, 'purple')
... )
{'color': 'red', 'foo': 'bar', 'number': 3}
```

If you have use for the number -> color mapping multiple times, define it outside and assign a name to it.

If `x` is not found in the dictionary, the fallback value `'purple'` will be returned by `get`.

Comment: Although this is my preferred method as well, this does not use the if-conditional that the OP asked for.

Comment: @Goodies right, the answer is meant as a suggestion. I'm assuming OP primarily wants to know how to handle decision making when creating his dict.

Comment: I prefer this compared to chaining of conditionals. Nice answer.

Comment: @Goodies, may be OP doesn't know that issue can be solved without if-conditional.

Comment: @germn Very true. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: @germn - OP doesn't know that the issue can be solved without if-conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Little addition. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35962823/1113207) with if-conditions may look more nice with some formatting (especially if you have many conditions):

```
x = 3
d1 = {
    "number": 3,
    "foo": "bar",
    "color": 
        "blue" if x == 1 else 
        "red" if x == 2 else 
        "purple"
}
```